Configurar cuenta gMsa + Xampp
Consulta estoy configurando una cuenta gMsa en un servidor que tengo instalado Xampp (Apache + Mysql), cuando cambio el local system en el apache 2.4 el servicio se funciona, pero el servicio mysql no funciona, por lo que no me funciona, trate de incluir la cuenta gMsa para que utilo para el Mysql pero no me funciona, existe la posibilidad de poder hacer funcionar con cuenta gMsa
dejar la cuenta en los dos servicios, pero no funciona

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Creo que fue por la traducion.
Tengo configurada una cuenta gMsa para administrar servicios windows. El servidor donde lo quiero configurar tiene una página web que está configurada con Xampp (Apache + Mysql). El servicio de Apache me queda running con la cuenta gMsa creada (quiere decir que levanta la página web interna;pero si esta misma cuenta la quiero usar para el servicio mysql no queda running el servicio por lo que si quiero guardar un dato me indica que no puede ser guardado en la base de datos. Entendería que es por el servicio y la cuenta gMsa que no arranca.
